# Am I entering this 2-variable recurrence correctly?

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

I'm trying to solve this recurrence with two variables.

```
RSolve[g[d, n] == 1 + g[d - 1, n] + g[d - 1, n - 1] && 
  g[d, 0] == g[0, n] == 0, g[d, n], {d, n}]
```

My boundary conditions are that `g[d, 0] == g[0, n] == 0` for all `d,n` .
But when I plug this in, I get the same input back with no error message.

Am I inputting the recurrence incorrectly? Or is *Mathematica* simply unable to find a closed form?

Comment: I believe that you are using the correct syntax.

Comment: It is a known sequence http://oeis.org/search?q=10%2C+55%2C+175%2C+385%2C+637%2C+847%2C+967%2C+1012%2C+1022%2C+1023&language=english&go=Search